# ABC conjecture consequence

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

At page 6 of the book: **"Prime Numbers The most mysterious figures in Math"** this statement is listed as one of the consequences of the ABC conjecture:

**There are Infinitely many Wieferich primes.**

This doesn't seem right to me? Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement would be that ABC implies there are infinitely many **non**-Wieferich primes.

(Of course, if ABC is true and there are also infinitely many Wieferich primes, then in a technical sense $\mathsf{T}\implies\mathsf{T}$ is true even without one being "deduced" from the other.)

Comment: Curious, Wikipedia says; The set of Wieferich primes and the set of non-Wieferich primes, sometimes denoted by W2 and W2c respectively,[34] are complementary sets, so if one of them is shown to be finite, the other one would necessarily have to be infinite, because both are proper subsets of the set of prime numbers.

Comment: Yes, that Wikipedia excerpt is correct. However, proving that one of them is **infinite** does **not** tell us anything about the other.

Comment: Ok, someone should inform the author then or perhaps an Errata is needed.